# modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-aloop not found / linstall inux-modules-extra-5.4.0?

Tags: package-management, sound, kernel

Hey I'm trying to run "modprobe snd-aloop pcm_substreams=1", unfortunately I keep getting an error and can't get any further. I tried it on my local Linux as well as on my Ubuntu server where I want to get it to work. Can someone help?

(Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS):

```
modprobe: FATAL: snd-aloop module not found in /lib/modules/5.4.0 directory
```

I read snd-aloop is in linux-image-extra and tried to install it too:

```
root@v33476:/home/youtube# sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Cannot find package linux-modules -extra -5.4.0 E: Could not find package from glob 'linux-modules-extra-5.4.0'
```

Comment: Your kernel doesn't seem to be an Ubuntu standard kernel. The 5.4 series should be something like `5.4.0-126-generic` resulting in `/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-126-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-aloop.ko`.

Comment: I tried to install this package but i get the following back: 
apt install http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-126-generic_5.4.0-126.142_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux

Comment: I have installed linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-40-generic_5.4.0-40.44~18.04.1_amd64.deb on the same way i dont know why it doesnt work with the 5.4.0-126-generic

Comment: What is your running kernel `uname -a`.

Comment: Linux v33476.1blu.de 5.4.0 #1 SMP Tue Jan 25 12:49:12 MSK 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Your kernel is unfamiliar, and likely unsupported here. Check your kernel configuration to determine if the desired module was even included. `grep CONFIG_SND_ALOOP /boot/config-5.4.0` you should get `CONFIG_SND_ALOOP=m`. If you get "y" then it is compiled in and not a module. If you get `is not set` then it was not compiled at all and is not available.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an unsupported kernel.

Run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

and reboot.

It should install a correct kernel and the modules.

Comment: No that is not working for me. Still the same error.